# Finding handle for Edit Control

Tags: c++, sendmessage, editcontrol

I am trying to find a handle for an Edit control in a window in another application. Basically what I have done so far is the following:

I already have the handle to the window in which the combo box of the edit control and edit control are in. I am using the EnumChildWindows() function to look through all the child windows of the parent window until I hit the Edit control:

```
HWND hWnd;//handle to parent window... I already have this
HWND handleEditControl;//I am looking for this

EnumChildWindows(hWnd, EnumChildProc, 0);

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{

  if (HERE IS THE PROBLEM)
  {
     handleEditControl = hWnd;
     return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

The problem I have is how to identify if the specific handle I am analysing is a handle for an Edit control or not. Might there be a msg for the SendMessage() function which identifies what type of a control the handle is for?...

Question:: How do I check if a handle that I have is from an Edit Control?

PS: The Edit Control doesn't have a name in the application I am using, so for that reason I am interested in knowing the type.

Comment: GetClassName() can tell you that it is an Edit control.  GetDlgCtrlID() *might* tell you that it is the specific edit control you are looking for.  Use Spy++ to look at the window properties.

Comment: Cool I'll try that out now. I used Spy++... the edit control doesn't have a name so for that reason I am trying to find out if it is an edit control

Comment: GetClassName() worked perfectly, thanks